# PIL opens only first chanel of TIF image

Tags: python-imaging-library

I'm trying to open (and then process) a 3-channel Tif image (8-bits) created with ImageJ.

```
im = Image.open('spinal.tif')
im.show()
```

shows me a png for the first channel

```
n = np.array(im)
print(n.shape)
```

gives me (400, 450), thus considers only the first channel

How could I work on the different channels? Many thanks

```
Info on my tif file from ImageJ:
Title: spinal.tif
Width:  1986.4042 microns (450)
Height:  1765.6926 microns (400)
Size:  527K
Resolution:  0.2265 pixels per micron
Voxel size: 4.4142x4.4142x1 micron^3
ID: -466
Bits per pixel: 8 (grayscale LUT)
Display ranges
  1: 0-255
  2: 0-255
  3: 0-255
Image: 1/3 (c:1/3 - 64_spinal_20x lame2.ndpis #1)
  Channels: 3
  Composite mode: "grayscale"
```

The file is temporarily available here :
https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=ab39ca56-24c3-4993-ae78-19ac5cf916ee

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way around using the **scikit-image** library.
This opens correctly the 3 channels (matplotlib didn't, nor PIL).
Once I have the array, I can go back to PIL using **Image.fromarray** to resume the processing.

```
from skimage.io import imread
from PIL import Image

img = imread('spinal.tif')
im_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
im_pil.show()
print(np.array(im_pil).shape)
```

This shows the composite image, and the correct (400, 450, 3) shape.
I can then get the different channels with **Image.getchannel**(channel) as in :

```
im_BF = im_pil.getchannel(0)
im_BF.show()
```

Thank you to the contributors who tried to solve my issue (I saw that the file was downloaded several times) and there might be a better way to process these multiple-channels TIF images with PIL, but this looks like working !

Answer (score 1):

Your image is not a 3-channel RGB image. Rather, it is 3 separate images, each one a single greyscale channel. You can see that with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick identify spinal.tif
spinal.tif[0] TIFF 450x400 450x400+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 545338B 0.000u 0:00.000
spinal.tif[1] TIFF 450x400 450x400+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
spinal.tif[2] TIFF 450x400 450x400+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Or with `tiffinfo` which comes with `libtiff`:

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Subfile Type: (0 = 0x0)
  Image Width: 450 Image Length: 400
  Resolution: 0.22654, 0.22654 (unitless)
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Rows/Strip: 400
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  ImageDescription: ImageJ=1.53f
images=3
channels=3
mode=grayscale
unit=micron
loop=false

TIFF Directory at offset 0x545014 (850f6)
  Subfile Type: (0 = 0x0)
  Image Width: 450 Image Length: 400
  Resolution: 0.22654, 0.22654 (unitless)
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Rows/Strip: 400
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  ImageDescription: ImageJ=1.53f
images=3
channels=3
mode=grayscale
unit=micron
loop=false

TIFF Directory at offset 0x545176 (85198)
  Subfile Type: (0 = 0x0)
  Image Width: 450 Image Length: 400
  Resolution: 0.22654, 0.22654 (unitless)
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Rows/Strip: 400
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  ImageDescription: ImageJ=1.53f
images=3
channels=3
mode=grayscale
unit=micron
loop=false
```

If it is meant to be 3-channel RGB, rather than 3 separate greyscale channels, you need to save it differently in ImageJ. I cannot advise on that.

If you want combine the 3 channels into a single image on the command-line, you can do that with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick spinal.tif -combine spinal-RGB.png
```

---

If you want to read it with PIL/Pillow, you need to treat it as an image sequence:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

with Image.open("spinal.tif") as im:
    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
        print(frame)
```

which gives this:

```
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=L size=450x400 at 0x11DB64220>
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=L size=450x400 at 0x11DB64220>
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=L size=450x400 at 0x11DB64220>
```

Or, if you want to assemble into RGB, something more like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open image and hunt down separate channels
with Image.open("spinal.tif") as im:
    R = im.copy()
    im.seek(1)
    G = im.copy()
    im.seek(2)
    B = im.copy()

# Merge the three separate channels into single RGB image
RGB = Image.merge("RGB", (R, G, B))
RGB.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks you @MarkSetchell ! 
Yes indeed the original image is not RGB but as it also has 3 channels I was expecting PIL to deal with it the same way (which would be OK for my purpose). 
I tried the "seek" function without success, I hadn't exactly understood how this works ; thank you for sharing this solution !
So far, I think that the "two-line" option of going through scikit-image `imread` and then `Image.fromarray` is shorter and suits my needs. I don't which one is more efficient and/or pythonic though.
Thank you again.

Comment: Actually, your solution is better, @Mark, because if the image has only two channels (which happens sometimes in my case), the `imread` from scikit-image doesn't work properly (it inverts the dimensions) and then I cannot perform the `Image.fromarray`. Your solution is cleaner and safer to face all different configurations...